# Converting SQL query to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a problem when I'm trying to pass a query with subquerys to Eloquent. I'm using Laravel 5.3.31 and the IDE crashes in the line `})->on('Trackings.user_id', '=', 'u.id');`.

The problem of Eloquent is when you have to put joins with subqueries, so I need help for that because I don't know where is the problem...

This is the query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name FROM users u
INNER JOIN perfil p ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE p.user_id = p.empresa_id 
    AND p.activo = 1
    AND p.user_id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT uemp.id
        FROM users u
        INNER JOIN perfil p ON p.user_id = u.id
        INNER JOIN users uemp ON uemp.id = p.empresa_id
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT ut.user_id, MAX(created_at) AS Fecha 
            FROM users_trackings ut 
            WHERE ut.created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH 
            GROUP BY user_id
        ) AS Trackings ON Trackings.user_id = u.id
        GROUP BY uemp.id
    ) 
    AND p.user_id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT uemp.id
        FROM usu_ser_param usp
        INNER JOIN usu_ser us on us.id = usp.usu_ser_id
        INNER JOIN servicios s on s.id = us.servicio_id
        INNER JOIN users u on u.id = us.user_id
        INNER JOIN perfil p on p.user_id = u.id
        INNER JOIN users uemp ON uemp.id = p.empresa_id
        WHERE usp.parametro_id = 3
            AND p.activo = 1
            AND 
            (
                (s.appnombre = 'platform1' AND s.ruta = 'platform1.index') 
                OR (s.appnombre = 'platform2' AND s.ruta = 'platform2.index') 
                OR (s.appnombre = 'platform3' AND s.ruta = 'platform3.index')
            ) 
            AND usp.valor NOT LIKE 'https://FR%' 
            AND usp.valor NOT LIKE 'https://platform2.FR%'
        GROUP BY uemp.id
    );
```

And this is my laravel eloquent code:

```
$result = Users::join('perfil as p', 'p.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->whereColumn('p.user_id', 'p.empresa_id')
        ->where('p.activo', 1)
        ->whereNotIn('p.user_id', function($sq1) {
            $sq1->from('users as u');
            $sq1->join('perfil as p', 'p.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
            $sq1->join('users as uemp', 'uemp.id', '=', 'p.empresa_id');
            $sq1->join('users_trackings', function($join) {
                $join->selectSub(function($sq2) {
                    $sq2->select('users_trackings.user_id', 'MAX("users_trackings.created_at") as Fecha');
                    $sq2->where('users_trackings.created_at', '>=', 'NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH');
                }, 'Trackings');
            })->on('Trackings.user_id', '=', 'u.id');
            $sq1->select('uemp.id');
            $sq1->groupBy('uemp.id');
            $sq1->get();
        })
        ->where('usu_ser_param.parametro_id', 3)
        ->whereNotIn('p.user_id', function($sq3) {
            $sq3->from('usu_ser_param as usp');
            $sq3->join('usu_ser as us', 'us.id', '=', 'usu_ser_param.usu_ser_id');
            $sq3->join('servicios as s', 's.id', '=', 'us.servicio_id');
            $sq3->join('users as u', 'u.id', '=', 'us.user_id');
            $sq3->join('perfil as p', 'p.user_id', '=', 'u.id');
            $sq3->join('users as uemp', 'uemp.id', '=', 'p.empresa_id');
            $sq3->where('usu_ser_param.parametro_id', 3);
            $sq3->where('p.activo', 1);
            $sq3->where(function($sq4) {
                $sq4->where(['s.appnombre' => 'platform1', 's.ruta' => 'platform1.index']);
                $sq4->orWhere(['s.appnombre' => 'platform2', 's.ruta' => 'platform2.index']);
                $sq4->orWhere(['s.appnombre' => 'platform3', 's.ruta' => 'platform3.index']);
            });
            $sq3->where('usu_ser_param.valor', 'not like', "https://FR%");
            $sq3->where('usu_ser_param.valor', 'not like', "https://platform2.FR%");
            $sq3->select('uemp.id');
            $sq3->groupBy('uemp.id');
        })
        ->get();
```

Any help or something?

Comment: you can output sql by ->sql() and compare it with your query.

Comment: I can't, because the query builder fails and show me this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::on(). The problem is in "})->on('Trackings.user_id', '=', 'u.id');" of the line 13.

Comment: have you looked at subquery joins? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins

Comment: Yes, but this link is for Laravel 8.x, and my Laravel version is 5.3.31, version from 2018. I can't upgrade it because is a production system. So, I have to achieve this in this version...

Comment: Note that Laravel 5.x is not supported anymore and you should update to a newer version... Apart from that you get the error that the on() method does not exist in querybuilder... so look at the documentation on joins

Comment: got you, I took a look and laravel 5.3 doesn't have subquery joins

Comment: Since Laravel 5.3 doesn't support subquery joins and you can't upgrade, why don't just DB::select("your sql query")

Comment: @AnuratChapanond I can't, I used DB::select('u.id, u.name FROM users u
INNER JOIN perfil p ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE p.user_id = p.empresa_id 
    AND p.activo = 1
    AND p.user_id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT uemp.id
        FROM users u
        INNER JOIN perfil p ON p.user_id = u.id...

And the error: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'u.id, u.name FROM users u...

It's curious because the query works in MySQL

Comment: do not omit SELECT before u.id

Comment: Ouch, I put the SELECT before u.id and now the error tells: Call to a member function get() on array. If I put toSql() I got the same, but Call to a member function toSql() on array

Comment: Hey!! It works!!! Looking for this, when you are a DB::select, you don't have to put get() at last. Without get() the query works. Thanks for help!